# Como faço para o refresh do Datepicker funcionar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Primeiramente vou falar como este datepiker funciona, ele tem de seguir diversas regras, o que dificulta a criação do código. Posso usar somente um datepicker para a seleção das datas, tanto de entrada e saída, e após ser selecionada a primeira data, somente os sete dias seguintes podem ser selecionados e quando a mesma data for selecionada, (como entrada e com saída), devesse dar um refresh no datepicker.

Consegui fazer praticamente tudo funcionar, exceto a parte do refresh, vi em diversos lugares diversas formas de fazer, porém não obtive sucesso. Troquei o refresh por destroy e funciona, porém preciso que funcione com refresh, alguém pode esclarecer o que estou fazendo de errado e ou me mostrar como fazer o refresh funcionar no meu código?

```
<style type="text/css">
.dp-highlight a.ui-state-default:nth-of-type(1) {
    background: #4176A2 !important;
}
</style>    
<div class="calendario_dias_reservas">
    <div id="date1" class="datepicker_reservas"></div>
</div>


$(".datepicker_reservas").datepicker({        
    minDate: 0,
    numberOfMonths: [1, 4],
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {            
        var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#datepicker_entrada").val());
        var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#datepicker_saida").val());
        return [true, date1 && ((date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2)) ? "dp-highlight" : ""];
    },
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {

        if($("#datepicker_id").val() == '' || $("#datepicker_id").val() != inst['id']){
            $("#datepicker_entrada").val('');
        }
        var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#datepicker_entrada").val());
        var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#datepicker_saida").val());
        var selectedDate = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, dateText);

        if (!date1 || date2) {
            $("#datepicker_entrada").val(dateText);
            $("#datepicker_saida").val(""); 
            $("#datepicker_id").val(inst['id']); 
            var data = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', dateText);
            data.setDate(data.getDate('dd/mm/yy') + 7);                 
            $("#"+inst['id']+"").datepicker( "option", "minDate", dateText);   

            $("#"+inst['id']+"").datepicker( "option", "maxDate", data);
            $(this).datepicker();
        } else if (selectedDate < date1) {
            $("#datepicker_saida").val($("#datepicker_entrada").val());
            $("#datepicker_entrada").val(dateText);
            $(this).datepicker();
        } else {
            if(dateText != $("#datepicker_entrada").val()){
                $("#datepicker_saida").val(dateText);
                $(this).datepicker();
            }else{
                console.log(inst['id']);
                $("#"+inst['id']+"").datepicker("refresh");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não consegui utilizar o método refresh em meu datepicker, então tentei encontrar uma medida alternativa.. Não é o jeito mais correto, porém resolveu o meu problema.

```
onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {

        if ($("#datepicker_id").val() == '' || $("#datepicker_id").val() != inst['id']) {
            $("#datepicker_entrada").val('');
        }
        var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#datepicker_entrada").val());
        var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#datepicker_saida").val());
        var selectedDate = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, dateText);
        if (!date1) {
            $("#datepicker_entrada").val(dateText);
            $("#datepicker_saida").val("");
            $("#datepicker_id").val(inst['id']);
            var data = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', dateText);
            data.setDate(data.getDate('dd/mm/yy') + 7);
            $("#" + inst['id'] + "").datepicker("option", "minDate", dateText);
            $("#" + inst['id'] + "").datepicker("option", "maxDate", data);
            $(this).datepicker();
        } else if (selectedDate < date1) {
            $("#datepicker_saida").val($("#datepicker_entrada").val());
            $("#datepicker_entrada").val(dateText);
            $(this).datepicker();
        } else if (date1 && date2) {

//Eis aqui a solução; Verifico se as duas datas já existem
//Se existirem então reseto todos os valores "manualmente"
//Fazendo com que o datepicker "resete"

            date1 = false;
            date2 = false;
            $("#datepicker_entrada").val("");
            $("#datepicker_saida").val("");
            $("#" + inst['id'] + "").datepicker("option", "minDate", 0);
            $("#" + inst['id'] + "").datepicker("option", "maxDate", null);
        } else {
            if (dateText != $("#datepicker_entrada").val()) {
                $("#datepicker_saida").val(dateText);
                $(this).datepicker();
            } else {

//E aqui utilizo o mesmo método 
//Para resetar o datepicker quando a segunda data for igual a primeira

                date1 = false;
                date2 = false;
                $("#datepicker_entrada").val("");
                $("#datepicker_saida").val("");
                $("#" + inst['id'] + "").datepicker("option", "minDate", 0);
                $("#" + inst['id'] + "").datepicker("option", "maxDate", null);
            }
        }
    }
```

Como eu disse não é o meio mais correto já que existe uma função específica para isso, porém foi a solução e o meio que consegui encontrar, espero que possa ajudar mais alguém com algum problema parecido.